# Integration of Probability density function

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I have a question on how this equation changes from Probability Density Function to Cumulative Density Function. The equation

$\int U(W)[f(W)-g(W)]\mathrm dW > 0$

changes into

$\int U(W) \mathrm d[F(W)-G(W)] > 0 $

where $f(W)$ and $g(W)$ refer to Probability Density Function and $F(W)$ and $G(W)$ refer to Cumulative Density Function.

Can anyone explain to me how both equation are the same. Having difficulty understanding the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a probability distribution $P$ has a cdf $F$, and is absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure with density $f$, you have $F^\prime=f$, i.e. $dF(x)=f(x)dx$.

$$
\frac{d}{dx}F(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{(-\infty,x]} P(dt) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{(-\infty,x]} f(t)dt = f(x)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the cumulative density function is $F(W)=P(W \leq w)= \int_{-\infty}^{w} f(w)dw$  thus if we differentiate it we will get $f(W)$. Same goes for $G$